# can struct type itself be passed to function as parameter in c?

Tags: c, wayland

While studying wayland protocol, I found code that functions takes struct type as parameter.

```
#include <wayland-server.h>    
static struct wl_compositor_interface compositor_interface =
        {&compositor_create_surface, &compositor_create_region};

    int main() {
        wl_global_create (display, &wl_compositor_interface, 3, NULL, 
                          &compositor_bind);
    }
```

signature of wl_global_create is

```
struct wl_global* wl_global_create  (struct wl_display *display,
                                     const struct wl_interface *interface,
                                     int    version,
                                     void *data,
                                     wl_global_bind_func_t bind)
```

wl_compositor_interface is structure type, not a variable name. but wl_global_create() take structure type as function parameter.
can someone explain how this works?

the source code I read is here. https://github.com/eyelash/tutorials/blob/master/wayland-compositor/wayland-compositor.c

Comment: Have you tried to *build* the code? Does it build? Have you checked that there's no code generated by the build-system that contains a *variable* with that name (it's allowed to have a structure and variable with the same name)?

Comment: yes, I compiled the code and gcc did not give any warning or errors. environment is  ubuntu 17.04. I don't remember the gcc compiler version, but i think it is above version 5. and there was no files that declares variable with that name

Comment: Bottom line: no.  But note that in the code fragments you present, `wl_compositor_interface` *is not* a structure type, it is a structure ***tag***.  Nothing you show makes it meaningful in C when not proceeded by the `struct` keyword.

Comment: You might be able to kitbash something together with a macro, or define an enumeration whose values represent types, but this is something built into C++, not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I browsed through the source code, and there is both a `struct wl_compositor_interface` and a variable `wl_compositor_interface`.

The included [`wayland_server.h`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland/tree/src/wayland-server.h) includes, at the bottom, `wayland-server-protocol.h`.  Unfortunately, this is not available online, but is generated at build time. You can get it with:

```
$ git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland
$ cd wayland
$ mkdir prefix
$ ./autogen.sh --prefix=$(pwd)/prefix --disable-documentation
$ make protocol/wayland-server-protocol.h
```

In this file, it has the (somewhat confusing) definitions:

```
extern const struct wl_interface wl_compositor_interface; // On line 195
...
struct wl_compositor_interface { // Starting on line 986
    void (*create_surface)(struct wl_client *client,
                   struct wl_resource *resource,
                   uint32_t id);

    void (*create_region)(struct wl_client *client,
                  struct wl_resource *resource,
                  uint32_t id);
};
```

It's the `struct` that's being referenced the first time, and the variable the second.