# in wayland source code, I cannot find in which file, variable is defined

Tags: protocols, wayland

this is questions raised from [can struct type itself be passed to function as parameter in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101813/can-struct-type-itself-be-passed-to-function-as-parameter-in-c?noredirect=1#comment75224943_44101813)

from the previous question, I found that "wl_compositor_interface" is used as struct tag and variable both in header file "wayland-server-protocol.h".

```
struct wl_compositor_interface {
         void (*create_surface)(struct wl_client *client,
                                struct wl_resource *resource,
                                uint32_t id);
         void (*create_region)(struct wl_client *client,
                               struct wl_resource *resource,
                               uint32_t id);
 };


extern const struct wl_interface wl_compositor_interface;
```

however, the header file just declared the variable as `extern const struct wl_interface wl_compositor_interface;` I cannot find where the variable is defined. similarly, all variables with pattern "wl_***_interface are declared in the header file but have no definition.
can someone help me to find the definition?
wayland source is here [wayland github](https://github.com/wayland-project/wayland)

I also looked at documentation, there was no description about wl_***_interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `struct wl_interface wl_compositor_interface` - that you have to use when binding to the wl_compositor global - is in the generated protocol code, usually in `$SRC/protocol/wayland-protocol.c`.

The `struct wl_compositor_interface` is the structure used by the compositor to register functions where it will receive requests from clients (for its own wl_resource structs that represent the compositor global seen by the clients).